# Plot Multiple Column in a Time Space Graph

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a data frame with following structure (Space wise Arrival and Departure Times of two events, U1 and U2). I am trying to plot a time-space diagram such that the x axis shows the Time scale, and y axis shows the Spaces. I have tried few things, such as plot function, however, could not mange to plot it. Any one can help me for this? Thanks!

```
  Space  U2       U1
  A      16:14:00 16:29:00
  A      18:56:00 19:05:00
  B      19:14:00 19:16:59
  B      19:32:00 19:39:59
  C      19:50:00 19:57:59
  C      20:10:59 20:15:00
  D      16:21:00 16:39:00
  D      16:32:00 16:54:00
  E      16:48:59 17:10:00
  E      17:01:59 17:24:00
```

**Update**: I have been able to plot something with ggplot, however, the jump points between spaces are not connected. Any idea how can I connect them?

```
df%>% mutate(Space= factor(Space, levels=unique(Space))) %>% gather(var,     val, -Space)%>% ggplot(aes(Space, val, color = var,group = interaction(val,Space,var)))+ geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of OP's requirements is as follows:

1. The first row of each space gives the arrival time and the second row the departure time. So, the arrival time of event `U1` at space `A` is 16:29 and the departure time is 19:05.
2. In the chart, the arrival and departure times for each event and space shall be connected by a line segment with the times along the x-axis and the spaces along the y-axis.

To plot the line segments using `geom_segment()` the data need to be reshaped so that arrival and departure times appear in two columns within one row instead of two rows one below the other. This is achieved by using `melt()` and `dcast()` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)   #CRAN version 1.10.4 used

# use chaining, start with converting a copy of df to class data.table
pd <- data.table(df)[
  # reshape from wide to long form to get all events in one column,
  # thereby renaming conveniently
  , melt(.SD, id.var = "Space", variable.name = "Event", variable.factor = FALSE)][
    # reshape from long to wide to get arrival and departure times 
    # for each space and each event in one row
    # use factor to give meaningful names to  columns (instead of numbers)
    , dcast(.SD, Space + Event ~ factor(rowid(Space, Event),  
                                        labels = c("Arrival", "Departure")))]

pd
```

> ```
>     Space Event  Arrival Departure
>  1:     A    U1 16:29:00  19:05:00
>  2:     A    U2 16:14:00  18:56:00
>  3:     B    U1 19:16:59  19:39:59
>  4:     B    U2 19:14:00  19:32:00
>  5:     C    U1 19:57:59  20:15:00
>  6:     C    U2 19:50:00  20:10:59
>  7:     D    U1 16:39:00  16:54:00
>  8:     D    U2 16:21:00  16:32:00
>  9:     E    U1 17:10:00  17:24:00
> 10:     E    U2 16:48:59  17:01:59
> ```

Now, the reshaped data can be plotted:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pd) + 
  aes(x = Arrival, xend = Departure, y = Space, yend = Space, colour = Event) + 
  geom_segment() + 
  geom_point() + geom_point(aes(x = Departure)) + 
  xlab("Time") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that some line segments do overlap but start and end points are indicated.

Other options to avoid overplotting would be facetting or to plot an interaction variable `interaction(Space, Event)` (or `interaction(Event, Space)` for a different order) on the y-axis.